# How to implement navigation bars like here?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

It's in fact a picture.

See `#navMain` in [this page](http://www.thenetcircle.com/)

Best in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

It uses multiple graphics in a single image file. It uses background position to adjust between the different menu items. Its [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

It reduces the amount of HTTP requests and improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ues [menu with animation](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/) or something simpler. The only thing you need to do is to add some active css style to outline selected menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. it uses 1 background image within the css file on hover. it could also be a wordpress plug-in since it is on wp.